# EKM rotation in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, key, google-cloud-kms, key-management

I have concerns about key rotation management in GCP. If we use Fortanix as an EKM and implement a rotation every 30 days, do we need to manually update the key reference on the GCP side, or is it possible to automate this process?

When we define a Key in Fortanix we give the URL to cloud team to configure the EKM functionality. Now, if we rotate this what shall we do on GCP side? The URL contains th KeyID reference that will change. So, i think that each time we rotate the key, our colleagues will need to update the URL in GCP.

> Is there any way to automate this process?